# Spring in Kotlin: Extracting Object from ServerRequest

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-kotlin

I'm building a Spring microserves that is using Functional `coRouter`

```
 @Bean
    fun directoryRoutes(phoneDirectoryController: PhoneDirectoryController): RouterFunction<*> {
        return coRouter {
            GET("/directory") {serverRequest ->
                ServerResponse.accepted().bodyAndAwait(phoneDirectoryController.searchDirectory(request = serverRequest))
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to extract the dto object from the body

```
data class SearchDirectoryDto(
    val firstname: String,
    val secondName: String,
    val thirdName: String,
    val lastname: String
)
```

I used the ways described in the Spring documentations and other sites, like

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-request

like this for instance

`val item = request.awaitBody<SearchDirectoryDto>()`

but all of the functions gave me

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-05-04T18:31:46.979+00:00",
    "path": "/directory",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "requestId": "de9e7a88-1"
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
2023-05-04T21:31:46.981+03:00 ERROR 47367 --- [or-http-epoll-2] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [de9e7a88-1]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/directory"

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value received via onNext for awaitSingle
    at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.AwaitKt$awaitOne$2$1.onComplete(Await.kt:282) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactive-1.6.4.jar:na]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/directory" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
        at kotlinx.coroutines.reactive.AwaitKt$awaitOne$2$1.onComplete(Await.kt:282) ~[kotlinx-coroutines-reactive-1.6.4.jar:na]
        at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onComplete(StrictSubscriber.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onComplete(Operators.java:2205) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:102) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onComplete(FluxPeek.java:260) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.5.5.jar:3.5.5]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:413) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:431) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:663) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:113) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:274) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.1.6.jar:1.1.6]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) ~[netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:333) ~[netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:454) ~[netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290) ~[netty-codec-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:800) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:499) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:397) ~[netty-transport-classes-epoll-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.91.Final.jar:4.1.91.Final]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-05-04T21:31:47.026+03:00  WARN 47367 --- [or-http-epoll-2] r.n.http.server.HttpServerOperations     : [de9e7a88-1, L:/127.0.0.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:42906] Decoding failed: FULL_REQUEST(decodeResult: failure(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)), version: HTTP/1.0, content: UnpooledByteBufAllocator$InstrumentedUnpooledUnsafeHeapByteBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 0, cap: 0))
GET /bad-request HTTP/1.0
```

I can't use any object i send in API requests...

how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the headers of the postman, I forgot that I disabled all the headers.
after enabling the headers of `Content-Type`, `Content-Length` and others, all worked fine...